# Contours differences between C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm currently using opencv to detect simple countours on shapes. At first, I used c++ and everything worked well. Now, I'm trying to do the same with Python as I need to use it online, and the contours detection doesn't seem to be working as well.

Here is my c++ code :

```
_src = cv::imread(_imagePath);
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(_src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat bw;
cv::Canny(gray, bw, 0, 50, 5);
cv::findContours(bw.clone(), allCountours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

As you can see, it's quite simple, the same code is Python is :

```
self._src = cv2.imread(self._imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(self._src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bw = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 50, 5)
allCountours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

To show the results, i used drawcontours with random colors on the different contours :

[image]

As you can see, in c++ each shape contour is detected properly, evn though it's not perfect, whereas in Python I have much more contours. Every time a line breaks a little, a new contour is detected. Any idea how I could fix this ? Thanks you !

Comment: I would like to congratulate you. This is the best OpenCV question I've seen in a long time. Keep it up!

Comment: I smell a bug, you might want to upload your testimage as well. If somebody else with Python (i only use c++) can verify it, you should probably take it to the opencv forum.

Comment: Why don't you put an issue here: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues

Comment: Difference may be result of bug in findContours but it may be result of bug that happened prior to it. Canny, cvtContours and even imread can be the guilty ones. Please verify that _src, gray and bw are identical in C++ and Python (you can use some simple function like sum() for sanity check).

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov I just did a quick sanity check. `sum()` returns different results after applying `Canny`. This may be the culprit.

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov _src and gray are identical, but bw is different so I think that yeah, Canny is responsible for the delta between the two results. If it can help, this is the image I'm trying to interpret :
http://hpics.li/2cb0ca3 (the part I posted earlier is only the top).
For the record, I want to get the shapes, ideally only the corners of each shape, so that I can automatically draw the ground map in a 3D editor.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ function signature is as follows:
    `void Canny(InputArray image, OutputArray edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int apertureSize=3, bool L2gradient=false )`

And for Python it is:
    `cv.Canny(image, edges, threshold1, threshold2, aperture_size=3) → None`

As you can see, the last parameter is unavailable in Python. It might be the case that it is set to  `true`. Could you try that?

Comment: This is a good intuition, but the [`cv2.Canny()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#cv2.Canny) docs do show the `L2gradient` parameter. I still get differing results even when this parameter is set the same.

Comment: Yep, the results are the same wether I explicitely put the apertureSize and L2gradient or not.

Comment: Could you post the test image? Perhaps we can work something out.

Comment: @AdamKosiorek It's this one : http://hpics.li/2cb0ca3. I only posted the upper part here.